# Why is my BLE device data FFFFFFF from config index?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Basically, I am supposed to retrieve a value from a Bluetooth LE skincare device. Among the services that the device has, the device has a configuration service, with two characteristics: one for reading/writing data, and another characteristic for reading and writing the configuration value.

I have the document that shows all the UUID's, their characteristics, properties, values etc. The configuration indexes are all listed in the file too, and preprogrammed in the device.

Goal: This is where I am stuck. One of the config indexes has a value of 12. I have to write the config index to the characteristic, and then in return, the program will read the data corresponding to the configuration index, and print the data on the terminal. I sent a value as 0C (12 in hex), and ended up with FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. It has to be a different value.

How can I achieve this goal?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
while (true)
            {
                if (device == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to pair the device.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to pair with device");
                    GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();

                    if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        var services = result.Services;

                        foreach (var service in services)
                        {
                            if (service.Uuid.ToString() == configSvc)
                            {
                                GattCharacteristicsResult charactiristicResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                                if (charactiristicResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                {
                                    var characteristics = charactiristicResult.Characteristics;
                                    

                                    foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
                                    {
                                        GattReadResult rResult = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();
                                        GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
                                        if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
                                        {

                                            var writer = new DataWriter();
                                            GattCommunicationStatus wResult = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

                                            if (characteristic.Uuid.ToString() == configIdxCt)
                                            {
                                                int psCalVal = 12;

                                                //var startCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(psCalVal.ToString());
                                                //Console.WriteLine(startCommand[0]);
                                                writer.WriteByte(0xc0);

                                                if (wResult == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("message sent successfully");
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on writing to characteristic!");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
                                       {
                                            
                                            if (rResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                            {

                                                if (characteristic.Uuid.ToString() == configValCt)
                                                {
                                                    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(rResult.Value);
                                                    byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                                                    reader.ReadBytes(input);

                                                    //Console.WriteLine(input[0]);
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Data: ");
                                                    string psCArrayWDash = BitConverter.ToString(input) + " ";
                                                    string psCArray = psCArrayWDash.Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                                                    Console.WriteLine(psCArray);
                                                }
                                                if (characteristic.Uuid.ToString() == measurementCt)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Read");
                                                    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(rResult.Value);
                                                    byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                                                    reader.ReadBytes(input);

                                                    Console.WriteLine("Data: ");
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                                                        Console.WriteLine(input[i].ToString() + " ");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");

                                        }
                                            
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Please, make sure the device is connected, and try again.");

                    
                }
            }
            deviceWatcher.Stop();
```

Comment: What does happen when you use your code?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Ran the code. Wrote 0C (12 in hex) and ended up with FFFFFFFFFFF. Something is wrong.

Comment: Have you confirmed the correct return value through a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Could you link the documentation as well?